# Using multiple Match Group with Windows OpenSSH

Tags: ssh, configuration, sftp

Trying to configure the sshd_config to restrict depending on which AD group you belong. The goal was to have it that when you connect it would ChrootDirectory to the only directory you had access to. Also have the permissions on the folder in Windows configured correctly. However, I'm getting "Failed password for invalid user user1" if I use more than one "Match Group". As soon as I comment out the other "Match Groups" it works.

Match Group from sshd_config

```
AllowGroups "Domain\HBRobot-SFTP" "Domain\HBRobot-SFTP-FG" "Domain\HBRobot-SFTP-SF" "Domain\HBRobot-SFTP-Shared" "Domain\HBRobot-SFTP-MF"

#Main AD group to see all subfolders and files
Match Group Domain\HBRobot-SFTP
       ChrootDirectory "D:\HB_RA_SFTPFileShare"

# AD group for FG reports folder
Match Group Domain\HBRobot-SFTP-FG
       ChrootDirectory "D:\HB_RA_SFTPFileShare\FG"

#AD group for SF reports folder
Match Group Domain\HBRobot-SFTP-SF
       ChrootDirectory "D:\HB_RA_SFTPFileShare\SF"

#AD group for Shared reports folder
Match Group Domain\HBRobot-SFTP-Shared
       ChrootDirectory "D:\HB_RA_SFTPFileShare\Shared"

#AD group for MF reports folder
Match Group Domain\HBRobot-SFTP-MF
       ChrootDirectory "D:\HB_RA_SFTPFileShare\MF"
```

This is what I'm seeing in the logs:

```
1304 2022-01-19 14:09:21.010 debug1: userauth-request for user fuh0d9q service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
1304 2022-01-19 14:09:21.010 debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
1304 2022-01-19 14:09:21.057 debug1: user C:\\Users\\user1 matched group list Domain\\HBRobot-SFTP at line 37
1304 2022-01-19 14:09:21.073 debug1: get_passwd: LookupAccountName() failed: 1332.
1304 2022-01-19 14:09:21.073 debug1: Can't match group at line 41 because user n does not exist
1304 2022-01-19 14:09:21.183 debug1: get_passwd: LookupAccountName() failed: 1332.
1304 2022-01-19 14:09:21.183 debug1: Can't match group at line 45 because user n does not exist
1304 2022-01-19 14:09:21.417 debug1: get_passwd: LookupAccountName() failed: 1332.
1304 2022-01-19 14:09:21.417 debug1: Can't match group at line 49 because user n does not exist
1304 2022-01-19 14:09:21.605 debug1: get_passwd: LookupAccountName() failed: 1332.
1304 2022-01-19 14:09:21.605 debug1: Can't match group at line 53 because user n does not exist
1304 2022-01-19 14:09:21.636 debug1: userauth-request for user user1 service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
1304 2022-01-19 14:09:21.636 debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
1304 2022-01-19 14:09:21.636 debug1: keyboard-interactive devs  [preauth]
1304 2022-01-19 14:09:21.636 debug1: auth2_challenge: user=fuh0d9q devs= [preauth]
1304 2022-01-19 14:09:21.636 debug1: kbdint_alloc: devices '' [preauth]
1304 2022-01-19 14:09:26.699 debug1: userauth-request for user user1 service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
1304 2022-01-19 14:09:26.699 debug1: attempt 2 failures 1 [preauth]
1304 2022-01-19 14:09:26.699 debug1: Windows authentication failed for user: NOUSER domain: . error: 1326
1304 2022-01-19 14:09:26.699 Failed password for invalid user user1 from ***.**.***.** port 57106 ssh2
1304 2022-01-19 14:09:33.409 debug1: userauth-request for user user1 service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
```